# Am I leaking memory in a loop?

Tags: c#, loops, memory-leaks

I'm a new programmer and I just come up with a question of memory leakage. Am I leaking memory if I declare a variable in a loop to make it be declared again and again?
For example, I have

```
while(true)
{
    Image<Gray, Byte> MyImage = new Image<Gray, Byte> (1024, 768);
    //do something else
}
```

I know it's an infinite loop but my question is about the memory. Is the memory usage growing fast in this loop? Should I release MyImage manually?

Comment: I'd hazard a guess, and say yes... but I'm not 100% sure, so please don't take it as gospel.

Comment: @Killercam Are you sure? Because I hear something different and I don't know. Do you mean it's okay with the Image object in this case, or generally speaking?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to call `MyImage.Dispose()` after using it.

Another way is to change the code to:

```
while(true)
{
    using(Image<Gray, Byte> MyImage = new Image<Gray, Byte> (1024, 768)){
        //do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: I realized maybe the class don't implement `IDisposable`. So, take it  if a- it implements IDisposable or b- it uses something that implements IDisposable, in which case you should implement it for disposing the internal objects.

Comment: Is this just for efficiency or it's a real memory leak?

Comment: Classes that are IDisposable usually make use of memory that cannot be free until Dispose() method is called. As you may be using them in a infinite loop, it could cause memory leaks (I mean, if you are using Disposable objects without calling Dispose, it WILL cause memory leaks)

Comment: Emgu.CV.Image<TColor, TDeep> If you know anything about OpenCV, Image is a C# managed wrapper of IplImage and it does have a Dispose method

Comment: Perfect then. Call `Dispose()` or use the `using` statement :)

Answer (score 3):

The Garbage Collector (GC) will do this work for you - eventually. In cases like you propose, you must be careful, as the GC in this case will try and manage the time it spends doing garbage collection vs. the applications memory consumption (the working set). Consequently application can consume more memory than it needs especially in cases like you illustrate.

The CLR handles this memory entirely automatically and you never deallocate managed memory yourself. For example consider the following

```
public void Test()
{
    byte[] myArray = new Byte[1000];
    // ...
}
```

when `Test` executes, an array to hold 1000 bytes is allocated on the memory heap. The array is reference by the variable `myArray`, stored on the local variable stack. When this method exits, this local variable pops out of scope, meaning that nothing is left to reference the array on the memory heap. The orphaned array then becomes eligible to be reclaimed by the GC. However, this collection may not happen immediately as the CLRs decision on whether to collect is based on a number of factors (available memory, the current allocation of memory, the time since last collection etc.) tThis means that there is an indeterminate delay on the time taken before garbage collection.

In light of the above, in the case you describe, you will get a vast increase in memory consumption for the duration of the loop/containing method. here it is much better to either use a `using` statement

```
while (true)
{
    using (Image<Gray, Byte> MyImage = new Image<Gray, Byte> (1024, 768))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or by calling `dispose()` on the `Image` object after each loop.

```
while (true)
{
    Image<Gray, Byte> MyImage = new Image<Gray, Byte> (1024, 768);
    // ...
    MyImage.Dispose();
}
```

*Asside: you can always check such memory consumption out for yourself (testing your processes real memory consumption) by querying a performance counter (using System.Diagnostics):*

```
string procName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
using (PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Private Bytes", procName))
    Console.WriteLine(pc.NextValue());
```

*Note: Reading performance counter requires administrator privileges.*

Answer (score 1):

> Am I leaking memory if I declare a variable in a loop to make it be declared again and again?

No, you don't, the problem as mentioned by others could be if Image is wrapping an Image object

But for your question, it is not a problem to declare a variable inside a loop and assign it with a new value on each iteration

Answer (score 1):

There are situations where tight loops can cause OOM issues.  However, `Image` implements `IDisposable` so be sure to call it via a `using` statement so the resources can be freed up when you are done with them.

```
using (Image<Gray, Byte> MyImage = new Image<Gray, Byte>(1024, 768))
{
  //do stuff
}
```

Make sure `Image<T,U>` implements `IDisposable` if `Image<T,U>` implements any managed objects.

Answer (score 1):

In the general form of your question, you are not leaking memory per se, but you are possibly increasing your memory footprint faster than the GC will reduce it (depends on the exact behavior and memory seize of the objects you are using).  If so, this will have a lot of memory leak-like effects.

In your specific example, Image objects hold unmanaged resources, which may include memory (or file handles, or GDI objects, etc).  As the other answers note, if you do not dispose, those unmanaged resources will not get reclaimed (or may be reclaimed on the GC's second pass, if they have a finalizer).